# Common conditions for *NgIf in Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm developing a frontend using angular 11 and there are multiple places where I need to apply ***ngIf** with the same condition,

```
<mat-option *ngIf="horizontalStepperForm.value.step2.companyType == 'Head_Office'" value="Light">Light</mat-option>
<mat-option *ngIf="horizontalStepperForm.value.step2.companyType == 'Head_Office'" value="Basic">Basic</mat-option>
<mat-option *ngIf="horizontalStepperForm.value.step2.companyType == 'Head_Office'" value="Professional">Professional</mat-option>
```

These values are capturing from a FormGroup and are there any way to resolve this same condition using a method to reduce hard coding the same thing everywhere in the HTML?

Comment: putting a method call `*ngIf=checkVisibility()`  on html is not recommended. Reason being, the method will be called every 1-2 seconds (because it is triggered by every change detection) . Try putting `console.log` in any such method and see it for yourself. I can give few suggestion. Create a constant variable with string `Head_office` or you can also set boolean value by subscribing to `horizontalStepperForm.valueChanges.subscribe( data => {}) ` . Let me know if you need more clarification on this

Comment: @ShashankVivek That logic is called a lot during the Angular redraw cycle regardless of whether you put it in a method or not.  I do not understand how using a constant would solve that, nor what you'd do in `valueChanges` to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a function in the component class:

```
isCompanyTypeHeadOffice() {
    return horizontalStepperForm.value.step2.companyType == 'Head_Office'
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
<mat-option *ngIf="isCompanyTypeHeadOffice()" value="Light">Light</mat-option>
<mat-option *ngIf="isCompanyTypeHeadOffice()" value="Basic">Basic</mat-option>
<mat-option *ngIf="isCompanyTypeHeadOffice()" value="Professional">Professional</mat-option>
```

We do this thing a lot; not just for repeated conditions, but I consider keeping logic in the template an anti pattern.  Better to put that logic inside the component class where it can be more easily unit tested.

Answer (score 0):

I still recommend it

```
 get bool():boolean{
    return this.horizontalStepperForm.value.step2.companyType == 'Head_Office'
  }
```

```html
<mat-option *ngIf="bool" value="Light">Light</mat-option>
```